pass dimens or macros as parameters to a lua function
I have this Lua function:
-- ratio of dimensions
function ptLuaGetRatio(val1, val2)
  local ratio = val1 / val2
  tex.print(string.format("%0.5f", ratio))
end

In LuaTeX I want to call it this like:
\directlua{ptLuaGetRatio(\dimen0, \dimen1)}

or in a macro like this:
\def\ptLuaGetRatioInTeX#1#2{\directlua{ptLuaGetRatio(#1, #2)}}
\ptLuaGetRatioInTeX{\dimen0}{\dimen1}

These calls produce this error:
unexpected symbol near '\'.

Calling \directlua{ptLuaGetRatio(1, 2)} works without error.
Okay, I do not know how to pass TeX-dimens or TeX-macros as arguments to a lua function. Can anyone help?
Thanks
Peter


\dimen0 is seen by Lua as literally that string, you want it to expand and expand to a number not a length with a unit:

\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function ptLuaGetRatio(val1, val2)
  local ratio = val1 / val2
  tex.print(string.format("%0.5f", ratio))
end
}
\endgroup


\dimen0=100pt
\dimen2=30pt

or in a macro like this:

\def\ptLuaGetRatioInTeX#1#2{%
    \directlua{ptLuaGetRatio(\number\dimexpr#1\relax, \number\dimexpr#2\relax)}}

 \ptLuaGetRatioInTeX{\dimen0}{\dimen2}

\bye


Both solutions, David's and Udi's, work for me. Thank you both for your help! I chose David's solution, because it's easier to understand and more simple.

You  can use token.scan_dimen
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
local function ptLuaGetRatio()
  local val1 = token.scan_dimen()
  local val2 = token.scan_dimen()
  local ratio = val1 / val2
  tex.print(string.format("\csstring\%0.5f", ratio))
end
local ptLuaGetRatio_func = luatexbase.new_luafunction"ptLuaGetRatio"
lua.get_functions_table()[ptLuaGetRatio_func] = ptLuaGetRatio
token.set_lua("ptLuaGetRatioInTeX", ptLuaGetRatio_func)
}
\def\foo#1#2{\ptLuaGetRatioInTeX#1#2\relax}
\dimen0=20sp
\dimen1=10sp
\ptLuaGetRatioInTeX\dimen0\dimen1

\foo{\dimen0}{\dimen1}
\end{document}


I used your code (inside \directlua) together with \ptLuaGetRatioInTeX\dimen0\dimen1 in my project, but it says: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.71 \ptLuaGetRatioInTeX
\dimen0\dimen1

Does it matter, that I am using LuaTex, not LuaLaTex?

You will need to allocate the lua function yourself, without luatexbase.

I'll update the answer later.

@coonlight you can always not define it as a Lua function as well...

Oh, sorry Udi, my mistake! I forgot one line of your code! Your code works even in LuaTex.
